# Skip hidden step in stepy jQuery plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I need to skip a step in [stepy plugin](http://wbotelhos.com/stepy) but doesn't know how to. I'm using callbacks but don't work, this is my code:

```
    next: function(index) {
        console.log(index);
        if ($('#product_create-head-2').is(':hidden')) {
            $('#product_create').find('fieldset').eq(2).hide();
            $('#product_create').find('fieldset').eq(3).show();
            $('#product_create').stepy('step', 3);
        }
    },
    back: function(index) {
        console.log(index);
        if ($('#product_create-head-2').is(':hidden')) {
            $('#product_create').find('fieldset').eq(2).hide();
            $('#product_create').find('fieldset').eq(1).show();
            $('#product_create').stepy('step', 1);
        }
    }
```

By default `$('#product_create-head-2')` is hidden but can be displayed by user interaction so if it's hidden when I press next/previous it should skip this step and go to next/previous depending on user action, what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You can use "select" function of stepy in a code like this:

```
next: function(step){  // invoked by next button
          wzDir = 'fw'; //set direction forward
      },
back: function(step){  // invoked by back button
          wzDir = 'bw'; //set direction backward  
      },
select: function(step){
          if (step == 2){ //invoked on every selected step
            switch (wzDir){
              case 'fw': $('#product_create').stepy('step', 3); //jump to 3 
                         break; 
              case 'bw': $('#product_create').stepy('step', 1); //jump to 1
                         break; 
            }
          }
      }
```

This must works...